# Quartz net is not firing job in .NET 6 console application

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, console-application, quartz.net

I am trying to fire a job with Quartz net in .NET 6 but it seems something I am doing is wrong.

This is my scheduler code:

```
public  async Task  ScheduleQuartzNet()
{
    IScheduler scheduler = await StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
    await scheduler.Start();

    IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<BackGroundJob>().Build();

    ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(schd => 
        {
            schd.WithIntervalInSeconds(20);
            schd.OnEveryDay();
            schd.StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(21,59));
        })
        .Build();

    try
    {
        await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
        await scheduler.Shutdown();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

This is the Job itself

```
  public class BackGroundJob : IJob
  {
        private WorkerClass workerClass;

        public BackGroundJob(WorkerClass workerClass)
        {
            this.workerClass = workerClass;
        }

        public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            int  i = 10;

            while (i != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Job is triggered: {i} time.");
                await workerClass.DomSomeAsyncWork();
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is caller code

```
using BackgroundJob;

QuartzNetScheduler qs = new QuartzNetScheduler();
await qs.ScheduleQuartzNet();

Console.ReadLine();
```

What am I doing wrong ? Any time I schedule just does not work....any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are immediately shutting down the scheduler after you have scheduled your job.

You should replace `await scheduler.Shutdown();` with some sort of blocking mechanism (either a `Task.Delay(-1)` or `Console.ReadLine()` to stop your program from immediately exiting, too.

The [docs](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/quick-start.html#trying-out-the-application) outline this in one of their examples:

```cs
// some sleep to show what's happening
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));

// and last shut down the scheduler when you are ready to close your program
await scheduler.Shutdown();
```